# kill(pid,SIGTERM) terminates child process, although pid is of parent

Tags: c, process, signals

I'm learning about process allocation.

Take this code block for example:

```
int main(){
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        while(1)
            printf("Child ");
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i<1000;i++)
            printf("Parent ");
        kill(pid,SIGTERM);
        printf("\n%d \n ", pid);
    }
}
```

`pid = 0` is the child process, `pid > 0` is the parent process. `kill(pid,SIGTERM)` is executed by the parent with it's own `pid`, yet it kills the child and not itself. Why?

Comment: But `pid` holds the process ID of the child so it kills the child. I am confused, `fork` returns PID of the launched child, not the parent.

Comment: Read the documentation of `fork` again.

Comment: @Siguza
"On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child."
Everything makes sense now.

Comment: See also: [`raise`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/raise), [`getpid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Siguza mentioned in the comments, you should re-read the documentation of `fork`.  `fork` returns a positive value of `pid` to the parent process.  That value is the PID of the **child** process.  Therefore, `kill(pid, SIGTERM)` sends the signal to the child and not the parent.

Comment: Yes, found it there, thank you. My bad, I guess I didn't do enough research.